# Django redirects to different view when form action is set to "."

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I am lost here. I am quite new to django and maybe this is a newbie question.
I have a very simple list view , which shows the records in the database and a create view to add these objects :

```
@login_required
def list_view(request):
     objects = Foo.objects.all()
     ctx = {'objects': objects}
     return render_to_response('main/foos.html', ctx, 
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
@login_required
def create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FooForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/foos/')
    else:
        form = FooForm()
    ctx = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('main/foo_form.html', ctx, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The foo_form.html template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Club</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Url settings:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^foos/$', 'list_view'),
                       url(r'^foos/new$', 'create_view'),
                       )
```

When I type the url "localhost:8000/foos/new", the create view gets the GET request as expected. The problem is, upon submitting the form, I am redirected to the list (using a debugger I found out the request is getting to the list_view), even when form action is set to "." 
What am I doing wrong? The create_view view should receive the POST request .
Any help is appreciated! Again, I am sorry if this is a newbie question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't finished the regex string in the second url

```
url(r'^foos/new$', 'create_view')
```

so "." will use the current url to POST the form. Django takes the url '/foos/new' and matches it against the regex. It matches the first regex, as it finds a match for 'foos', so goes to the 'list_view'. Just finish your regex correctly and it will work.

```
url(r'^foos/new/$', 'create_view')
```

Comment: Should not be a problem. The end slashes are put in there by django, by default.

Comment: @Games Brainiac - Incorrect, Django does not add the trailing slash to the regex, only the url itself. My answer is correct, easily replicated in my dev environment. Adding the trailing slash fixes the issue.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct, for others coming to this question if that's OK.

Comment: Sorry it took so long

Answer (score 1):

Leave the form action as "" to post to the same url rather than having a .

So in this case

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm/>
    </form>
```

Comment: It worked!! I knew this had to be stupid... Can you explain to me what does "." do then? Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I think it should have worked, potentially try changing the foo/new url to `url(r'^foos/new/$', 'create_view'),`

Comment: Also as a small tip adding a name to you urls as so `url(r'^foos/$', 'list_view', name='fooname'),` means you can do `return redirect('fooname')` so if you ever change the /foo/ url you don't need to change the rest of your code to match